# How to change the naming convention of Many-to-Many table relationships?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

How can I go about changing the naming convention of the auto-generated many-to-many table?

Assume I have two classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

By Default, this will create a table called **UserRoles**.

I can change the name of that **one** table to **UsersInRoles**, for example, by using the following in the OnModelCreating override of my DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Roles)
    .WithMany(p => p.Users)
    .Map(mc =>
    {
        mc.MapLeftKey("UserId");
        mc.MapRightKey("RoleId");
        mc.ToTable("UsersInRoles");
    });
```

However, what I really want to do is change the naming convention so that by default, all auto-generated many-to-many tables use this new convention.  I cannot figure out how to do that, or if it's even possible. I do not like having to specify 9 lines of extra code every time I specify one of these relationships.

I am currently using EF version 6.0.0-rc1.

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you really want to do that? Coding by convention loses all it's charm when you keep having different ones.

Comment: You could take a look at [Custom Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx).

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, In my real scenario, I am writing a framework that changes all table names with a prefix based on their "component" location (such as Core, HR, Finance, etc).  While I was able to write a catch-all for standard table renaming, it didn't work with these many-to-many tables, and I can't figure out how.  As for my example, I've used that convention for a long time, and would love to stick with it.

Comment: @GertArnold, I know you can write custom conventions, but still don't know how I would go about solving this particular problem, whether with custom conventions or directly with the DbModelBuilder.

Comment: Afraid I haven't an answer. I know there are ways of messing with the conventions, but I suspect they are deliberately painful.

Comment: Convention Over Configuration does't loose its charm because you want to use a different convention.  There are any number of reasons why someone might want to define their own conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to control relationships was removed from the basic conventions API before release because it wasn't in a usable state.  You can access all of the properties and tables in the model through model based conventions.  An overview of model based conventions is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469439

This solution involves a little more digging around in the metadata API, EntitySet is the correct type for this scenario

This convention should rename the generated relation table:

```
public class MyConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EntitySet>
{
    public void Apply(EntitySet set, DbModel model)
    {
        var properties = set.ElementType.Properties;
        if (properties.Count == 2)
        {
            var relationEnds = new List<string>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var metadataProperty in properties)
            {
                if (metadataProperty.Name.EndsWith("_ID"))
                {
                    var name = metadataProperty.Name;
                    relationEnds.Add(name.Substring(0, name.Length - 3));
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if (relationEnds.Count == 2)
            {
                set.Table = relationEnds.ElementAt(0) + "_" + relationEnds.ElementAt(1) + "_RelationTable";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I played around with this some, but found that the EntityType convention doesn't allow me to rename tables.  The Set Name property is internal.  So again, I'm stuck with having to rename each table manually.

Comment: Does the convention above solve your problem or is there something else that you need?

Comment: No, that is perfect! Can't say I'm nearly as familiar the EDM portion as I should, but this is working great.  Thanks!